# Card.io: WebViewActivity destroyed on getting result

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent, card.io

I have implemented the card.io Android SDK in a special way: 
I have a webView, where a button is implemented. This button has a special URL. When this URL is catched by the WebViewClient in the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method, the card.io scanner Intent is called:

```
    if( StringUtils.contains( url, "activity_scan_activity://scan_activity" ) ) {
            Intent scanActivity = new Intent(NativeBridgeActivity, CardIOActivity.class);
            scanActivity.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, true); // default: false
            scanActivity.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, false); // default: false
            scanActivity.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_POSTAL_CODE, false);
            scanActivity.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_HIDE_CARDIO_LOGO, true);
            scanActivity.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_EXPIRY, true);
            scanActivity.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CARDHOLDER_NAME, true);

            scanActivity.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_CONFIRMATION, false);

            NativeBridgeActivity.startActivityForResult(scanActivity, 9374);
}
```

In the WebViewActivity, which extends the abstract Class NativeBridgeActivity, the onActivityResult method is implemented and should be called, but the WebViewActivity is destroyed in all cases: when I press the back button on the scannerActivity, when I scan a creditCard and also when I press the keyboard button in the scanner activity.

My WebView Activity is an AppCompatActivity, which is extending a FragmentActivity. The WebView itselve is no Fragment!

Can anybody help me with this problem? I cannot find, where the onDestroy is called. finish is never called in this flow!

Answer (score 1):

I've found the bug. The WebView was laoded with no_history flag on one special place. all other ways where working correctly.

Question can be closed.